# Writing multiple queries to single csv

Tags: c#, csv, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to write multiple queries to a single CSV file. For example I will generate a report with an Employee Schedule then below that in the same CSV I want to see the employee personal information such as salary, office location, etc. I can return both queries from a single stored procedure thinking it would write one followed by the next, but apparently that's incorrect as only the first result is returned.

My SQL Query is like the following:

```
SELECT EmployeeSchedule.TaskTime, Employees.EmployeeName, EmployeeSchedule.M, EmployeeSchedule.Tu, EmployeeSchedule.W,
        EmployeeSchedule.Th, EmployeeSchedule.F, EmployeeSchedule.Sa, EmployeeSchedule.Su
FROM EmployeeSchedule
    INNER JOIN Employees on EmployeeSchedule.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
WHERE (
    EmployeeSchedule.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND
    EmployeeSchedule.TaskTime >= @ShiftStart AND 
    EmployeeSchedule.TaskTime <= @ShiftEnd AND
    (
        (EmployeeSchedule.M=1) AND (EmployeeSchedule.M = @M) OR 
        (EmployeeSchedule.Tu=1) AND (EmployeeSchedule.Tu = @Tu) OR 
        (EmployeeSchedule.W=1) AND (EmployeeSchedule.W = @W) OR 
        (EmployeeSchedule.Th=1) AND (EmployeeSchedule.Th = @Th) OR 
        (EmployeeSchedule.F=1) AND (EmployeeSchedule.F = @F) OR 
        (EmployeeSchedule.Sa=1) AND (EmployeeSchedule.Sa = @Sa) OR 
        (EmployeeSchedule.Su=1) AND (EmployeeSchedule.Su = @Su)
    )
)
ORDER BY EmployeeName, TaskTime


SELECT Employees.EmployeeName, Salary, City, AdditionalDetails
FROM EmployeeDetails
    INNER JOIN Employees on EmployeeDetails.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
WHERE Employees.EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
```

My relevant portion of code is as follows:

```
public void GenerateEmployeeLog()
{
string employee = Convert.ToString(EmployeesDropDown.SelectedItem.Text);

    string sqlConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(sqlConn))
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = ("usp_" + proc);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", Convert.ToString(EmployeeDropDown.SelectedItem.Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShiftStart", StartTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShiftEnd", EndTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("M", MCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tu", TuCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("W", WCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Th", ThCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("F", FCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sa", SaCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Su", SuCheckBox.Checked);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            dt.Load(reader);

                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream))
                            {
                                DataConvert.ToCSV(dt, writer, false);
                                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", @"attachment;filename=""" + "EmployeeLog - " + employee + @".csv""");
                                Response.Charset = "";
                                Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                                Response.End();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                        reader.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            sqlConnection1.Close();
            sqlConnection1.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm looking for is greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**
I ended up splitting out the two queries into different stored procedures and made the final modifications to my code, based on suggestions from the accepted answer below.

```
public void GenerateEmployeeLog()
{
string employee = Convert.ToString(EmployeesDropDown.SelectedItem.Text);

    string sqlConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(sqlConn))
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConnection1.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd1.CommandText = ("usp_" + proc + "_EmployeeDetails");
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd1.Connection = sqlConnection1;
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", Convert.ToString(AffiliatesDropDown.SelectedItem.Value));

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (dt1 = new DataTable())
                        {
                            dt1.Load(reader);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                        reader.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd2.CommandText = ("usp_" + proc);
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection1;
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", Convert.ToString(EmployeeDropDown.SelectedItem.Value));
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShiftStart", StartTextBox.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShiftEnd", EndTextBox.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("M", MCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tu", TuCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("W", WCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Th", ThCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("F", FCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sa", SaCheckBox.Checked);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Su", SuCheckBox.Checked);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt2 = new DataTable())
                        {
                            dt2.Load(reader);

                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream))
                            {
                                DataConvert.ToCSV(dt2, writer, false);
                                writer.WriteLine();
                                DataConvert.ToCSV(dt1, writer, false);

                                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", @"attachment;filename=""" + "EmployeeLog - " + employee + @".csv""");
                                Response.Charset = "";
                                Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                                Response.End();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                        reader.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            sqlConnection1.Close();
            sqlConnection1.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Mike U's 2nd approach very much, but if you absolutely must have one csv file output, its not pretty, but could you not do something like this?:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
    using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader()){
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()){
            using (DataTable dt1 = new DataTable()){
                dt.Load(reader);
                dt1.Load(reader1);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream)){
                     DataConvert.ToCSV(dt, writer, false);
                     DataConvert.ToCSV(dt1, writer, false);
                     ...
    }}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the `Response` stuff, you're doing this on a web page.  The problem you're going to run into is that you can only return a single response for a single request.  Since you're just sending the `DataConvert.ToCSV()` output as a response stream, that would mean a different stream for each of the files.

If you're not going to actually display these in HTML, then you'll need to create a ZIP file to store the two different files.

Examples for creating a multi-file ZIP file can be found here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT:  A second option would be to emit javascript into the Page_Load event which would call an HTTPHandler which actually runs the two separate queries.  This would popup two additional tabs, each with one of the CSV files.  You would have to move all this code into a custom HTTPHandler, where the querystring string parameter "t" could determine which of the two queries was run.

```
protected void btn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sysPgLoad = "Sys.Application.add_load(function () {{ {0}; }});";
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "employeeLog", string.Format(sysPgLoad, "window.Open('exployeeCsv.axd?t=log')"));
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "employeeSal", string.Format(sysPgLoad, "window.Open('exployeeCsv.axd?t=sal')"));
}
```

Comment: You are correct that I'm not displaying this in HTML, however, multiple files is not an option in this case including zipping them together. This report will be generated very frequently by managers and it must be in a single document. I'm open to any other suggestions that would allow me to create a single csv file.

Comment: You want two disparate data sets in a single file?  I don't think CSV is going to be able to do what you want, here, unless you're willing to simply "append" the second dataset to the response stream.  You *could* always just run a second query and write the output of `DataConvert.ToCSV()` to the Response.Stream before calling `Response.End()`, but then the file is going to be a little difficult to read.  You're bumping up against a limitation with the way the web works, not a lack of coding knowledge.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a second option, albeit quite a bit more complicated.